# How to increment a variable, and record value of a radio button over a series of pages?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button, increment

I am making a basic quiz program, that when finished will allow the user to complete quizzes being read from a MySQL database, and write quizzes to be stored in the database.

I have a variable for question number (`$qn`), which when incremented changes the question, and the four possible choices to the next question in the database.

My question is: How can I have a button on my main form, that (once the user has selected a radio button) recordes the radio button result, then increments `$qn` to display the next question, then does that process again, until `$qn == $numberOfQuestions`, at that point it needs to show the page results.php and add up the results from all the radio buttons on the quiz.php page.

I am quite new to PHP, so sorry if this is a particularly stupid question, or if I have worded it in an unclear way. And I am very open to suggestions is there is an easier or more efficient way of doing this.

Thank you in advance for any answers, really grateful :)

Comment: You're looking for a HTML form and their variables in PHP. You find the information in the PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just process the forms input, store the value and continue to the next question.

A rudimentary example ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BDH8TP)):

```
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<?php
$quiz = load_quiz();
$states = isset($_GET['state']) ? explode(',', $_GET['state']) : array();
$states = array_map('intval', $states);
$page = count($states)+1;

if (isset($_POST['answer']))
{
     $states[$page-1] = (int) $_POST['answer'];
}

if ($page > count($quiz))
{
?>
<h2>Your selection:</h2>
<?php
foreach($quiz as $key => $question)
{    
    $state = $states[$key];
    $answer = $question['answers'][$state];
    printf('%s: %s<br />', $question['question'], $answer);
}

}
else
{
?>
<h2><?php echo $quiz[$page]['question']; ?></h2>
<form method="post" action="?state=<?php echo implode(',', $states); ?>">
<?php
foreach($quiz[$page]['answers'] as $key => $answer)
{
    printf(
        '<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer-%d" value="%d"><label for="answer-%d">%s<label><br>',
        $key, $key, $key, $answer
    );
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you should be using JavaScript with AJAX requests. To detect when you select a radio button is only possible with JavaScript. You can use a library to make your life easier like jQuery. Look into functions like the [onChange](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. And also [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)